# Aeron publication side concurrency issue on singleton request buffer

Tags: java, concurrency, buffer, aeron

is there any best practice to handle concurrency on publish side??
assume that we have a client that wants to handle 1 Million concurrent requests, these requests must send to the Aeron server-side via publication offer. now we have a singleton expandable array buffer that overwrites and is corrupted by concurrency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using a concurrent `Publication` and that is not the issue you have with concurrent access. The issue seems to be a shared buffer for the offer. To publish concurrently you can have thread local buffers to construct your messages within, or you can use `Publication.tryClaim` if the message length is less than MTU and construct the message using a thread local `BufferClaim` instance.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how the `Publication` is being created, i.e. the `io.aeron.Aeron#addPublication` returns an instance of the `ConcurrentPublication` class which as the name suggest can be used by multiple threads concurrently. The `io.aeron.Aeron#addExclusivePublication` on the other hand returns an `ExclusivePublication` instance which can only be used by a single thread.

@mohamadreza: Why would you use a single shared expandable array buffer?

Comment: We assume that having a singleton buffer instance will help us decrease GC operations & cost.

Comment: @MohamadReza then you would be better off with thread local buffers.

Answer (score 0):

From the description of the problem, you should benefit from using https://github.com/real-logic/agrona/blob/master/agrona/src/main/java/org/agrona/concurrent/ringbuffer/ManyToOneRingBuffer.java and then implement the MessageHandler that makes use of `io.aeron.ExclusivePublication#offer`.